# Python deleting input .txt strings, but ends up deleting every string in the txt file

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to delete the number I'm putting in my søk input, as well as the 3 other strings that follow, but it ends up deleting every single string in the txt file.  So if i want to delete "1" and the three words that follow, it instead deletes everything.

```py
import os

def slett():
    funnet = False

    søk = input('Søk etter studentnr')
    studentfil = open('student.txt', 'r')
    temp_fil = open('tempfil.txt', 'w')
    
    studentnr = studentfil.readline()

    while studentnr != '':
        fornavn = studentfil.readline().rstrip('\n') 
        etternavn = studentfil.readline().rstrip('\n')
        studie = studentfil.readline().rstrip('\n')
       
        if studentnr == søk:
            temp_fil.write(f'{studentnr}\n')
            temp_fil.write(f'{fornavn}\n')
            temp_fil.write(f'{etternavn}\n')
            temp_fil.write(f'{studie}\n')
        else:
            funnet = True

        studentnr = studentfil.readline()

    studentfil.close()
    temp_fil.close()

    os.remove('student.txt')
    os.rename('tempfil.txt', 'student.txt')

    if funnet:
        print('Filen er oppdatert')
        print('Hva vil du gjøre nå? 1 - Slett på nytt, 2 - tilbake til meny, 3 - Avslutt program')
        velg4 = input('Velg her')
        if velg4 == '1':
            print('Slett på nytt')
            slett()
        if velg4 == '2':
            print('Tilbake til meny')
        if velg4 == '3':
            print('Avslutt')
        else:
            quit

    else:
        print('Studentnr ikke gjenkjent')

slett()
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be the inverse: `if studentnr == søk:` - i.e. if the student number _does not_ match what you're searching for, you want to keep the student in the file by writing the current student to the tempfile, otherwise (if the student number matches) skip writing any information to the new file. You're also not doing `rstrip()` after reading the line with the student number, so it will contain a newline at the end.

Comment: I'd suggest repeating that in an answer, @MatsLindh - perhaps with an example of the fixed two lines. You already described the entire problem with the code.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that you're not doing `.rstrip` on the student number - only on the other fields. So when you're comparing against what the user entered in the `input` statement, you'll end up comparing one value with a newline at the end against one value without a newline at the end. Strip the newline before making the comparison:

```
studentnr = studentfil.readline().rstrip()
```

Then when you're deciding which entries to keep, your current comparison *only* includes those that match - i.e. the only entries you're moving from the old file to the new file is those that match. Since what you're trying to implement is a delete operation, only those that does not match should be moved to the new file (i.e. the inverse of what you're doing now):

Instead of:

```
if studentnr == søk:
```

.. you want:

```
if studentnr != søk:
```

My final suggestion would be to drop the Norwegian names for the variables and use english terms; it'll be easier for other people to help as well, and will probably be required in your future career.